# Swift 3 - InputStream

Tags: sockets, stream, swift3

This code was working without any problem in Swift 2.2, but after update my code to Swift 3 it´s not working anymore. Can you guys help me to discover the problem ? No connection at all.

```
var inputStream: InputStream?
var outputStream: OutputStream?
func startNetworkCommunicationWithServer(){
    let myApp  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let server = myApp.myDefaultHost.ip
    let port = 9090

    Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: server, port: port, inputStream: &inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)


    inputStream?.delegate = self
    inputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    inputStream?.open()

    outputStream?.delegate = self
    outputStream?.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    outputStream?.open()
    //print(inputStream?.streamStatus ?? "")
}
```

Comment: This is the issue with optional chaining everywhere: things fail silently. You should use conditional binding to unwrap `inputStream` and `outputStream`, and handle the cases when they're `nil`.

Comment: I just tried with conditional binding and i don't get any error too. I have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: Show your updated code, please

Answer (score 1):

Update your delegate function to this

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
   //code
}
```